# How Do I Select This Certain Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

Say I have the HTML:

```
<span class="random"></span>
<div class="parentdiv">
    <img src="" class="button">
</div>
<div class="content-one">
    <div class="content-two">
    </div>
</div>

<span class="random"></span>
<div class="parentdiv">
    <img src="" class="button">
</div>
<div class="content-one">
    <div class="content-two">
    </div>
</div>
```

I can currently select the div content-one using the following JavaScript:

```
$(".button").toggle(function(){
    $(this).parent().nextAll(".content-one").first().slideUp('slow');
},
```

How would I go about selecting the div `.content-two` instead? As I just can't work out what it would be!

The reason for this is there being multiple instances of the class on the page for toggle and so needing to select just the first instance of the `content-two` div for each button press.

Comment: Which element is the parent of `img.button`? It has no parent element in your markup!

Comment: You need to select the first `content-two` on the page, or the first immediately following the button clicked?

Comment: Select the first .content-two that is after the button pushed effectively.  @undefined I've changed my initial markup for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".button").toggle(function(){
  $(this).parent().nextAll(".content-one").find(".content-two").first().slideUp('slow');
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you just replace ".content-one" with ".content-two" ? Since you're selecting the class ".content-one" I would assume if you just changed it to the class you want instead it would work?

```
$(".button").toggle(function(){
    $(".content-two").first().slideUp('slow');
},
```

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: Well you'd think so, but for some reason it doesn't work. I think it's because .content-two is nested inside .content-one

Comment: `next` and `nextAll` look at siblings - not children. Try `.nextAll(".content-one").nextAll(".content-two")`, or `children(".content-two")`

Comment: er, I guess I ninja edited it a bit, but I'd think if you selected based on the class like so, and then get the first one then you should be able apply the slideUp fn to that div

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".button").toggle(function(){
  $(this).next(".content-one").children('.content-two').first().slideUp('slow');
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next(".content-one").first(".content-two").toggle('slow');
});
```

This will grab the .button clicked and then get the parent then get the next sibling with '.content-one' as a class then and grab the first child with '.content-two' as the class and toggle the display. Example: [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/GyQ4e/7/)

Answer (score 0):

play around with this:

```
$(".content-one:first").css({border:'3px solid red'});
$(".content-one:first div:first").css({border:'3px dotted blue'});

$("div").eq(2).css({border:'3px solid #003366'});
$("div:eq(2)").css({border:'3px dotted blue'});
$("div:eq(2)>div:first").css({border:'3px dotted blue'});
```

your question was not specific enough but one of those lines have your answer
also check this link to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/e7MCy/